# How to resolve conflict between two jQuery plugins?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, jquery, conflict

I'm using the *fancybox plugin*. It was working good. But when I installed *slider plugin* slider plugin working good but the *Fancybox plugin* stopped working, why is it show?  How can I remove that conflict?

I read somewhere that this problem occur due to conflict in jQuery. So, how can I resolve that conflict?

I used this code for slider plugin in page:

```
{{block type='imageslider/imageslider' template='imageslider/imageslider.phtml'}}
```

Comment: Make sure you're only loading jQuery once and call jQuery.noConflict(); after you load jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem Now , Jquery was loading twice so i removed one of that jquery from the plugin. Now its working fine .Thanks denial.